# SQlite With EF6 Errors adding null PK

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I admit I am new to SQLite. I have ported my DB from SSE 2012. I want my PKs to autoincrement. The SQLite documentation says pass a null in the PK and it will assign a value. But how to you get EF6 to do this? I am using DB first. Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ROISet (
    ROISetID INTEGER  DEFAULT NULL,
    ImageID  INTEGER  DEFAULT 0
                      NOT NULL,
    Modified DATETIME NOT NULL
                      DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ROISets PRIMARY KEY (
        ROISetID
    )
);
```

EF6 gives me this:

```
public ROISet()
{
    this.ROIs = new HashSet<ROI>();
    this.ROIs1 = new HashSet<ROI>();
    this.ROIGroups = new HashSet<ROIGroup>();
    this.ROIGroups1 = new HashSet<ROIGroup>();
    this.TestConfigurations = new HashSet<TestConfiguration>();
    this.TestConfigurations1 = new HashSet<TestConfiguration>();
}

public long ROISetID { get; set; }
public long ImageID { get; set; }
public System.DateTime Modified { get; set; }
```

I have tried changing long to long? but the I get a DbEntityValidationException that the field is required. So how do I add a record with knowing the PK up front?

Thanks,
Doug